# Define logged in user route for a profile page in next js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm using next js - redux for my web application. The app has a profile page which the user can utilise to view other users for example: `website.com/aadhit` would mean to visit the profile of aadhit and `website.com/robert` would mean the profile of robert.

I have trouble understanding, if the user is logged in, and his name profile was richard. I would like to go to `website.com/richard` and show his account page with the my profile tab selected, not to view his profile as a third party like `website.com/aadhit` or so. How is this possible in next js?

I am catching dynamic routes for the above, but if it was the logged in user, I would like to render the my profile page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu could check on page load if the id of the user that is shown on the page, is the same as the id of the logged in user. If so that is your page and you can show a different page

Comment: But Twitter is able to assign the route `https://twitter/username` to the my profile. Is there a way to assign a value to the router query ?? I would like to perform the same